# Convert url of image to actual image when opening document

Tags: java, image, swing, actionlistener, bufferedimage

When I open up my file in my text editor.  I am only getting the file's location in the text pane.  Am I making a simple mistake somewhere or is there a better way to do this?  Should I use an ArrayList to store the images locations?

Example of what is happening:  I have a file that has two lines...

---

C:\...\pic.png 
(picture description)

---

When I try to open up the file (after I save it in the text editor) it shows the actual location of the picture.  I want to be able to use BufferedImage to get the directory and add the image to the JTextPane.  Otherwise (if the text isn't a location), simply add the text to the text pane.

FYI: textArea is of type ***JTextPane***

**Code that opens my file**

---

```
// sb is my StringBuffer

try
{
    b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line;

    while((line=b.readLine())!=null)
    {
        if (line.contains("C:\\...\\Pictures\\"))
        {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(line));
            ImageIcon selectedPicture = new ImageIcon(image);
            textArea.insertIcon(selectedPicture);
        }

        sb.append(line + "\n");
        textArea.setText(sb.toString());
    }

    b.close();
}
```

---

If you have any questions about this code or need clarification, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: What's in the file? Why don't you simply use an HTML file?

Comment: Wouldn't the `textArea.setText` change all content if it gets executed after you did a `textArea.insertIcon` ? how does your input file look ?

Comment: @JBNizet It's a text file that I am trying to open up with my text editor application.

Comment: @ringbearer The set text function just adds all the content that is not a directory.  For example, I have a file that has two lines.  The first line is the location of a file ("C:\\...\\pic.png") and the second line is a description of the file (in text).  When I open up the file with my text editing application the location of the file shows up on the first line and the description shows up on the second line.  However, I am trying to convert the location to an actual image by checking to see if the text contains "C:\\" and using buffered image to find and add the image to the JTextPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. The way you are setting content on to the `JTextPane` is incorrect.
The basic trick is to get `StyleDocument` out of the `JTextPane` and then set a `Style` on the document. A style basically explains how the component needs to be rendered. For example, text formatting, image icons, spacing etc.

Given that following code will get you started.

```
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    try {
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("inputfile.txt"));
        String line;
        StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) textPane.getDocument();

        while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.contains("/home/user/pictures")) {
                Style style = doc.addStyle("StyleName", null);
                StyleConstants.setIcon(style, new ImageIcon(line));
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "ignore", style);

            } else {
                Style textStyle = doc.addStyle("StyleName", null);
                //work on textStyle object to get required color/formatting.
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n" + line, textStyle);
            }
        }

        b.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Wow, very cool!  Thank you so much for the help (especially the example).